# SQLiteQuery returns null cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I have the following database, which I've checked it has few records (is not empty). There is something wrong with my `selectLink()` method, because it returns `null` cursor (the idea was it should return a row of the given "_id".

Table creation:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table HttpLinks ( _id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,name text not null);";
```

Row retrieve:

```
public final static String ID="_id";
public final static String NAME="name"

public String selectLink(long id)   {
    String[] cols  = new String[] {NAME};
    Cursor mCursor = database.query(TABLE, cols, ID+"="+String.valueOf(id),null,null,null,null,null);
return mCursor.getString(0);
```

logcat error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the query does not return null clearly as you dont get a `NullPointerException` you get a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` because you are not calling `moveToFirst` before you use the cursor

right before this line

```
return mCursor.getString(0);
```

you need to do

```
mCursor.moveToFirst();
```

Comment: And to add to this, don't forget to close your cursor once you're done using it.